# pipeline with Azure DevOps does not reflect changes when deploying to my Standard Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-app-standard

After my cd pipeline is completed running on Azure DevOps and the deployment is succeded, the changes are not reflected on my Standard Logic App.

Any ideas why this might be ocurring? This is my template for the deployment.

```
        parameters:
        - name: integrationId
          type: string
          default: ''
        - name: environmentName
          type: string
          default: ''


        jobs:
          - job: Publish
            displayName: Publish

            steps:
            - task: CopyFiles@2
              inputs:
                contents:  | 
                  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/LogicApps/${{ parameters.integrationId }}/**
                targetFolder: 'project_output'

            - task: ArchiveFiles@2
              displayName: 'Create project zip'
              inputs:
                rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/project_output'
                includeRootFolder: false
                archiveType: 'zip'
                archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
                replaceExistingArchive: true

            - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
              displayName: 'Publish LogicApp Artifacts'
              inputs:
                targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
                artifact: 'artifact${{ parameters.environmentName }}'
                publishLocation: 'pipeline'

          - job: logicAppDeploy
            displayName: 'Deploy the Logic apps'

            steps:
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
              inputs:
                buildType: 'current'
                artifactName: 'artifact${{ parameters.environmentName }}'
                targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

            - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
              displayName: 'Deploy logic app workflows'
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: $(ARMConnection)
                appType: 'functionApp'
                resourceGroupName: rg-integrations-${{ parameters.environmentName }}
                appName: ${{ parameters.integrationId }}-${{ parameters.environmentName }}-temp
                package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip
                deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
```

I this is my project structure:

```
        | Artifacts
          || Maps 
            ||| MapName1
            ||| ...
          || Schemas
            ||| SchemaName1
            ||| ...
        | WorkflowName1
          || workflow.json
          || ...
        | WorkflowName2
          || workflow.json
          || ...
        | .funcignore
        | connections.json
        | host.json
```

Not sure what is the issue, because the deployment is marked as succeded, and on the standar logic app the logs for the deployment are also successful, i even tried restarting the logica app but the changes still not reflected.

Also when i do the deployment throught Visual Studio Code, the apps gets deployed wihtout issue. But i would like it to be deployed automatically with Azure DevOps pipeline

Comment: Do you check the files archived into the ZIP file? Are the latest updated files contained? You also need to see whether the checkout task has checked out the latest file version?

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT Yes, of course, it is linked with the GitHub repo, and yes. It takes the last version of the files. I see the zip is being created with the right files. Here are the logs ArchiveFiles@2 https://pastecode.io/s/2o4u212b 

Again, from the same folder I did the deployment with VS code, and worked. but for some reason, the pipeline doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below yaml pipeline to deploy 2 Azure Logic App projects successfully even after they are modified:-

**My** ***Azure Repos***:-

[image]

***YAML code:-***

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
      - development

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy files to artifact staging directory'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      **/*.json
      !**/bin/**
      !**/obj/**
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/LogicApp'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/LogicApp'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyBuildArtifact.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'Deploy logic app workflows'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxxx subscription (xxxxxxxxxxxe97cb2xx7)'
    appType: 'functionAppLinux'
    appName: 'siliconLA'
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyBuildArtifact.zip'
    deploymentMethod: zipDeploy
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**StateLess1:-**

[image]

**StateLess2 is empty:-**

[image]

Created sample connector in Stateless2 and pushed the updated code to Azure repos, And ran the pipeline again. The new connectors where deployed successfully in Stateless2 Workflow:-

***Added the connector locally and pushed this code to Azure repos:-***

[image]

***Azure DevOps pipeline output:-***

[image]

**`Stateless2 was updated with the connector successfully when I ran the pipeline again:-`**

[image]

Comment: Do you know how can i set it up to overwrite the integration each time a change is done? For example, right now if I make a change or add an integration I can see it reflected. but if I delete a workflow it does not get deleted from the already deployed app